# Facebook Graph API Embed Swf in News Feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I can use Facebook Graph API to share a link successfully. The link being shared has a og:video tag pointing to the swf. The swf is embedded correctly (i.e. i can click play button) on the user's profile feed. However, the swf is not embedded (i.e. no play button) on the user's news feed.

Is this expected? I would like the swf to be embedded correctly on both the news feed and the user's profile feed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - Adding the og:image tag on the link being shared fixed this.